# CountdownLatch Thread-Safety Check

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free

I've written this class as an exercise for a synchronization construct to be used across multiple threads.

The intent is to have worker threads `Increment()` it, do some work, then finally `Decrement()`it.

Meanwhile, when a master thread decides to shut down the program, it signals the threads using a `CancellationToken` and `Wait()`s on this structure until all threads have ceased (signalled by `_number` hitting zero).

I am depending mainly on the fact that Interlocked operations imply full memory fences. I am concerned with the read on the `Wait()` method, see the comment there.

```
public class CountdownLatch
{
    int _number;
    readonly ManualResetEventSlim _event;

    public CountdownLatch()
    {
        this._event = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref this._number);
    }

    public void Decrement()
    {
        int currentNumber;
        bool firstAttempt = true;

        do
        {
            currentNumber = this._number;
            if (!firstAttempt)
            {
                var spinWait = new SpinWait();
                spinWait.SpinOnce();
            }
            else
            {
                firstAttempt = false;
            }

            if (currentNumber == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to decrement past zero");
            }
        } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this._number, currentNumber - 1, currentNumber) != currentNumber);

        if (currentNumber == 1)
        {
            this._event.Set();
        }
    }

    public bool Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        // Should this be a volatile read: Volatile.Read(ref this._number) ?
        // AFAICT the memory barrier here would prevent instruction reordering
        // when the order of reads/writes matter, but here it doesn't. I just care
        // to have the latest value of this._number across all CPUs/cores.
        // Or does volatile read in C# specifically do both ?
        if (this._number == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return this._event.Wait(timeout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The Good

I don't write multithreaded code very often, so other reviewers will probably have other comments (read: I'm a [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) beginner myself), but I like what I'm seeing.

> ```
> Interlocked.Increment(ref this._number);
> ```

I don't see anything that could go wrong with this. This is how I've read a thread-safe increment should be done, using the `Interlocked` class.

> ```
> while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this._number, currentNumber - 1, currentNumber) != currentNumber)
> ```

Looks good to me. `currentNumber` belongs to the thread that's running this, so no thread can mess with *that* `currentNumber` while `currentNumber - 1` or `CompareExchange` is being evaluated, and again the `Interlocked` class at play has my full trust.

---

#### The Bad

Ignorance is bliss, nothing in sight.

---

#### The Ugly

The very first thing that jumped at me, is the abundance of redundant `this` qualifiers. They're not needed, you have underscores:

> ```
> int _number;
> readonly ManualResetEventSlim _event;
> ```

I like the underscore prefix, because it allows me to have a `_number` field and a `number` parameter or local variable, for example:

```
public CountdownLatch(ManualResetEventSlim event)
{
    _event = event;
}
```

The way I read `currentNumber`, *"current"* stands for *"current thread's working copy of `_number`"*. I find the name `number` conveys that more succinctly.

Comment: I was hoping for some feedback on thread-safety rather than code style :-). I use "this" to increase readability, it is part of a code convention I follow in all my code. Your understanding of "current" is exactly right. I meant to emphasize that I am making a copy of shared memory to a private variable.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough with threaded code to specifically address the read in `Wait`; I preferred leaving that to other reviewers. Remember that CR answers may address any aspect of the code; if you used ReSharper you'd see code inspections suggesting to remove the redundant `this` qualifiers (they'd show up faded, too). It might be personal preference, but I find non-needed qualifiers clutter up the code, whether it's `this` or a namespace.